# Distribution of random variable that represents the number of fallen points inside circle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Inside a circle square is inscribed. On a circle points are randomly thrown, independently one after another, until $8$ points have fallen inside a square. Let $X$ be a random variable that represents the number of fallen points. Find it's distribution.

I did it this way, I am not sure if it is correct:

$P(X=n) = \binom{n}{8}(\frac{m(S)}{m(C)})^8(1-\frac{m(S)}{m(C)})^{n-8};n=8,9...$

m(S) is area of square and m(C) is the area of circle

Comment: I think you meant to write $P(X=n)$. Almost there but note the last point has to have fallen inside the square so I think ${n\choose 8}$ is not what you want.

Comment: @MBW should it then be $\binom{n-1}{8-1}$?

Comment: I think that's correct